# Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

When I'm trying to insert a new record into a table, an exception is thrown and this is the message I get:

> Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client

I checked my PHP version, it's 5.6.31, the server is running version 5.6.34 of MySQL.

I have been able to check out some old suggested solutions but I don't have admin privileges to the server.

Comment: hi, paste some of your code too

Comment: It will be probably helpful:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33447/connect-error-2054-mysql-old-password-issue-still-not-solved